# retrieve only months with at least 28 sample days - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filtering

Hello to the people of the web,

I have a dataframe containing 'DATE' (datetime) as index and TMAX as column with values:
[tmax dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTMUP.png)

What i'm trying to do is checking for every month (of each year) the amount of samples (each TMAX column value is considered as a sample).
If I have less than 28 samples, I want to drop that particular month (of that particular year) and all it's samples.

I have the following code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv("2961941.csv")

    # set date column as index, drop the 'DATE' column to avoid repititions + create as datetime object
    # speed up parsing using infer_datetime_format=True.
    df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

    # create new table out of 'DATE' and 'TMAX'
    tmax = df.filter(['DATE', 'TMAX'], axis=1)
    # erase rows with missing data
    tmax.dropna()
    # create snow table & delete rows with missing info
    snow = df.filter(['DATE', 'SNOW']).dropna()
    # for index, row in tmax.iterrows():
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest trying the following.
Here I have highlighted the results of counting days in a month into a variable 'a'.
And then I filter the data in which there are less than 28 days in a month.
It worked for me.

```
a = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='DATE', freq="M")).transform('count')
print(df[a['TMAX'] >= 28])
```

Comment: Your solution has opened my eyes to the idea of grouping, which I am quite weak with at the moment, and it is definitely worth strengthening. Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel0x If you think my answer helped, I would be grateful if you vote for the answer (check the box below the upper and lower triangle).

Comment: Voted, and it will be 'Recorded', just it requires me to gain at least 15 points or so for it to appear on the platform. Will make sure it will in no time. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the upper triangle?

Comment: The upper triangle is to mark the usefulness of the answer (for everyone). The answer can be counted by the author of the topic. To do this, you need to set a check mark, it is located under the lower triangle (it should turn green). You don't need a rating to set a check mark. You can see in my profile in the answers how it looks.